# How to get dialog by id

Tags: android

I am presenting a dialog in my Activity via:

```
 FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        CitySelectionDialog dialog = new CitySelectionDialog(this);
        dialog.show(manager, "citiesDialog");
```

Using the key "citiesDialog", how can I get a reference back to the dialog? (I don't want to use instance variable)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use the method 'findFragmentByTag', as described here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#findFragmentByTag(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1):

Like Lauw describe use [**`findFragmentByTag`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#findFragmentByTag%28java.lang.String%29)
this is an example

```
Fragment myCitiesDialog = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("citiesDialog");
```